# Can Arg function in R give values greater than pi?

Tags: r

In R, the function Arg applied to a complex returns an angle between -pi and +pi. For example :
Arg((1+i)^5) = -2.356... (-3*pi/4 radians)

Could I have a function returning the positive angle, even greater than +pi? For example, I would like to have :
"function"((1+i)^5) = 3.926... (5*pi/4 radians)

It seems Arg is not adaptable ; maybe some other function exits in some package ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

5*pi/4 is the same as -3*pi/4. So you could do:

```
Arg_positive = function(complex) {
  initial = Arg(complex)

  ifelse(initial < 0,
         initial + 2*pi, 
         initial)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the remainder of the division to 2pi:

```
Arg((1+1i)^5) %% (2*pi)
#[1] 3.926991
```

Comment: That's perfect ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own function to address this issue.

```
pos.arg <- function(num)
{
  arg = Arg(num)
  if (arg < 0)
    arg <- arg + 2*pi
  arg
}

x <- complex(length.out = 1, 1, 1)
y <- x^5
pos.arg(y)
[1] 3.926991
```

Comment: Don't you think that @bramtayl answer is the same of this? Plus, this function is not even vectorized, while his is.